# (The men/Men) usually drive fast in this country

Tags: articles, definite-article

> **The men/Men** usually drive fast in this country

Which one should I use and please explain.

I am more inclined to "Men" but a native speaker told me to use "The men".

Comment: Hello @Mahmous. Welcome to ELL. Please take the [tour](https://ell.stackexchange.com/tour). Also consider repeating the main sentence in your question once again, as most people do not see the title once they focus of the question.

Comment: _The men [...]_ if talking about particular men. _Men [...]_ if talking in general.

Answer (score 1):

Statements:

The is always specific.
The men in this country drive fast. [specific to the place]

[as opposed to men in other countries]

Lack of the is a generality.
Men in this country drive fast. [a general category]

[as opposed to women, who, for example, drive slowly]

Many times either can be used. It depends on context.

- The apples are good. [**the ones** we are eating]
- Apples are sweet. [as opposed to lemons which are sour. General.]